# Solve $\sin(3x)\sin(4x)=\cos(4x)\cos(5x)$ (problem from a Swedish 12th grade ’Student Exam’ from 1931)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The equation
$$\sin(3x)\sin(4x)=\cos(4x)\cos(5x)\tag{1}$$
can be transformed by expanding in powers of $\cos(x)$ and letting $r=\cos(x)$;
$$128r^9-256r^7+160r^5-32r^3+r=0,$$
‘factor out’ the solution $r=0$;
$$128r^8-256r^6+160r^4-32r^2+1=0,$$
letting $s=2r$;
$$8s^4-32s^3+40s^2-16s+1=0,$$
letting $t=s-1$;
$$8t^4-8t^2+1=0,$$
letting $u=t^2$;
$$8u^2-8u+1=0,$$
which can be solved using the quadratic formula.
Going back through the steps gives the solutions to (1) as
$$x=\pm\arccos(...)+k\cdot2\pi$$
(18 solutions + period of $2\pi$).

Is there a simpler way to solve this equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

$$\cos x-\cos7x=\cos x+\cos9x$$

Use $$\cos9x=-\cos7x=\cos(\pi-7x)$$

Can you take it from here?

Or use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$0=\cos9x+\cos7x=2\cos x\cos8x$$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin (3 x) \sin (4 x)=\frac{1}{2} (\cos (x)-\cos (7 x))$$
and
$$\cos (4 x) \cos (5 x)=\frac{1}{2} (\cos (x)+\cos (9 x))$$
$$\frac{1}{2} (\cos (x)-\cos (7 x))=\frac{1}{2} (\cos (x)+\cos (9 x))$$
$$\cos(7x)+\cos(9x)=0$$
In the following equations $k$ is any integer $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$2\cos(8x)\cos x=0$$
$$\cos(8x)=0\to 8x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\to x=\pm\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{k\pi}{4}$$
$$\cos x=0\to x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$

Formulae can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Calling $a = 4x$ and $b = x$ we have

$$
\sin(a-b)\sin (a)-\cos(a)\cos(a+b) = \cos(b)\sin^2(a)-\cos(b)\cos^2(a) = \cos(b)\left(\sin(a)-\cos(a)\right)\left(\sin(a)+\cos(a)\right)=0
$$

or

$$
\cos(x)(\sin(4x)-\cos(4x))(\sin(4x)+\cos(4x))=0
$$

Comment: Nice. Possibly one could factor as $\cos(b)\bigl(\sin^2(a)-\cos^2(a)\bigr)=0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(b)\bigl(\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)\bigr)=0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(b)\cos(2a)=0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(x)\cos(8x)=0$.